# Dagger 2 and android Studio: working but can't see generated classes

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I'm trying to use Dagger 2 in an Android Studio Project. I've used the CoffeeMaker example. I've managed to make the app build and working however:
- I don't success in seeing the generated code.
- If I debug, I can't see it neither.
- Moreover DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee as marked as reed (Cannot resolve symbol)

My gradle files are:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mateuyabar.android.dagger2test"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false // ignoring some references from dagger-compiler
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    provided 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

}
```

Thanks

Comment: If it builds and works why concern yourself with finding the generated files from `Dagger`?

Comment: First of all, learn and understand. Second one debugging.

Comment: Where did you get the this example?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Example is the one in Dagger2 site. Its not for Android but I've just copied the classes to an Android project.

Comment: If their example did not work, I'd suggest you make a pull request to fix their example.

Comment: @JaredBurrows already accepted a solution.

Comment: Yes. That is why I said if their example **does not work** you should make a pull request to fix **their** example on their Github project page.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Example uses pow.xml, not gradle

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [Android-Apt plugin](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt) by Hugo Visser:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
  }

  dependencies {
    // the latest version of the android-apt plugin
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
  }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mateuyabar.android.dagger2test"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false // ignoring some references from dagger-compiler
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

Note the `apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0'` line as well. This should make the generated sources visible for AS.

Comment: I have of all of this, and still cannot import class: `DaggerMyComponent`. What else must you do to generate?

Comment: If you've set it up correctly, it should work. Generated files can be found in `/build/generated/source/apt/`, so you can verify if generation has run.

Comment: If you have multiple gradle files, try specifying the classpath of the dependency in your most top-level file.

For me, I have `project/build.gradle` and `project/app/build.gradle`. I applied the plugin in `app` but declared the dependency in `project` and it worked for me.

Comment: No need for apt. Android Gradle plugin now ships with support for annotationProcessor dependencies like dagger compiler

Answer (score 6):

I stumbled upon same problem, in my case I was testing new classes and tried to inject them separately into my main class, in that case Dagger won't generate any DaggerComponents from factory.

Simply, remember to put all injections that goes into one class in one Module & one Component. **You cannot inject more than one DaggerComponent into one class.** Besides that's the point of those components, to aggregate injected classes