# Dagger 2 - unable to inject object

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Im trying to do a very simple dependency injection in a Android app. I am using dagger 2 as a DI tool.

The issue is no injection is occuring:

here is my code:

//behold Motor.java in all its awe.

```
public class Motor {

    private int rpm;

    public Motor(){
        this.rpm = 10; //default will be 10
    }

    public int getRpm(){
        return rpm;
    }

    public void accelerate(int value){
        rpm = rpm + value;
    }

    public void brake(){
        rpm = 0;
    }
}
```

and here is the Vehicle.java which utilities the motor class:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;


public class Vehicle {

    private Motor motor;

    @Inject
    public Vehicle(Motor motor){
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    public void increaseSpeed(int value){
        motor.accelerate(value);
    }

    public void stop(){
        motor.brake();
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return motor.getRpm();
    }
}
```

I then created a VehicleModule.java class to define my provider:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import dagger.Module;
import dagger.Provides;



@Module
public class VehicleModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Motor provideMotor(){
        return new Motor();
    }

    @Provides @Singleton
    Vehicle provideVehicle(){
        return new Vehicle(new Motor());
    }
}
```

I then i have a interface component annotated, defined like this:

```
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import Modules.VehicleModule;
import dagger.Component;

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VehicleModule.class})
public interface VehicleComponent {

    Vehicle provideVehicle();

}
```

and here is my Android mainactivity class that should be injected but its not, can anyone help:

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Inject
    Vehicle vehicle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(vehicle.getSpeed()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

im getting a null pointer exception on vehicle:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int com.example.uen229.myapplication.Vehicle.getSpeed()' on a null object reference
```

by the way my gradle dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> here is my Android mainactivity class that should be injected but its not

You're expecting magical things happen when you annotate something with `@Inject`. While magical things *will* happen, it's not *that* magical. You will need to do that yourself, by instantiating the component implementations that Dagger generated.

You can do this in a couple of ways, I will describe two.

---

First, in your `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`:

```
private Vehicle vehicle; // Note, no @Inject annotation

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  VehicleComponent vehicleComponent = DaggerVehicleComponent.create();
  this.vehicle = vehicleComponent.provideVehicle();

  Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(vehicle.getSpeed()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

In this case, you create an instance of `VehicleComponent`, implemented by Dagger, and fetch the `Vehicle` instance from it. The `vehicle` field is not annotated by `@Inject`. This has the advantage that the field can be `private`, which is a good thing to want.

---

Secondly, if you do want Dagger to inject your fields, you need to add an `inject` method to your `VehicleComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {VehicleModule.class})
public interface VehicleComponent {

  Vehicle provideVehicle();

  void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

In your `MainActivity` class, you call `inject(this)`, which will fill the `vehicle` field:

```
@Inject
Vehicle vehicle; // Note, package-local

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  VehicleComponent vehicleComponent = DaggerVehicleComponent.create();
  vehicleComponent.inject(this);

  Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(vehicle.getSpeed()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This brings a bit of extra configuration, but is sometimes necessary.
I like the first method however.

---

As a final comment, let's have a look at your `VehicleModule`, and *really* use the power of Dagger.

Instead of using the module to create the instances yourself, you can make Dagger to that for you. You've already annotated the `Vehicle` constructor with `@Inject`, so Dagger will know to use this constructor. However, it needs an instance of `Motor`, which it doesn't know of. If you add an `@Inject` annotation to the constructor of `Motor` as well, and annotate the `Motor` class with `@Singleton`, you can get rid of the `VehicleModule` altogether!

For example:

```
@Singleton
public class Motor {

    private int rpm;

    @Inject // Just an annotation to let Dagger know how to retrieve an instance of Motor.
    public Motor(){
        this.rpm = 10; //default will be 10
    }

    public int getRpm(){
        return rpm;
    }

    public void accelerate(int value){
        rpm = rpm + value;
    }

    public void brake(){
        rpm = 0;
    }
}
```

Your `Vehicle` class:

```
@Singleton
public class Vehicle {

    private Motor motor;

    @Inject
    public Vehicle(Motor motor){
        this.motor = motor;
    }

    public void increaseSpeed(int value){
        motor.accelerate(value);
    }

    public void stop(){
        motor.brake();
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return motor.getRpm();
    }
}
```

You can now safely delete the `VehicleModule` class, and remove the reference to it in your `VehicleComponent`.

Comment: its saying it cant find DaggerVehicleComponent in the IDE.  any ideas ? i removed the Inject annotation and am following your first method so i can make private methods. its package local. Everythings package local now. but it does not find DaggerVehicleComponent.  Im guessing this is something thats auto generated.

Comment: Check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29707308/675383) for instructions on how to make Android Studio find the generated classes.

Comment: using this apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' and in the build.gradle file this:  classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'    made it auto generate the classes for me.  Your explanation is very good. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the following steps

you have create the module like this in application class

```
public class D2EApplication extends Applicaiton {
    public static D2EComponent component(Context context) {
            return ((D2EBaseApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).component;
        }

        public final static class DaggerComponentInitializer {

            public static D2EComponent init(D2EBaseApplication app) {
                return DaggerD2EComponent.builder()
                        .systemServicesModule(new VehicleModule(app))
                        .build();
            }

        }
    }
```

and inject it to the activity

```
D2EApplication.component(this).inject(this);
```